# Table view with list view

Tags: android

i need to use table view with list view..

1st column is fixed and can be scrolled vertically only and columns after that are vertically and horizontally scrollable
The functionality will be like table view is horizontally scrollable and on vertical scrolling of list the table view should also get scrolled.

Similar to what the TvListing of this app shows
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.xfinity.tv&feature=search_result

Anybody has any idea how the tvlisting UI is developed of this app as i need to work on similar lines...

Thanks

Comment: if anyone need any further explanation please let me know..

Comment: Well, I guess you have to try it out yourself and let us know the problem while implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use in this format . Just it is an example.

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="540dip"
            android:layout_height="215dip" android:background="#ffffff">
            <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:paddingRight="10dip">
                <TableRow>
                    <ScrollView>
                        <TableLayout android:layout_width="150dip"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingRight="10dip">
                            <TableRow>
                                <ListView android:layout_height="250dip"
                                    android:id="@+id/revenue_list_item" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:paddingTop="10dip"></ListView>
                            </TableRow>

                        </TableLayout>
                    </ScrollView>

                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
            <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="165dip"
                android:gravity="center">
                <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ScrollView>
                        <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">
                            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="180dip"
                                    android:layout_height="105dip" android:background="@drawable/graph_layout"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dip" android:id="@+id/image">

                                </RelativeLayout>
                                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="180dip"
                                    android:layout_height="105dip" android:background="@drawable/graph_layout"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dip" android:id="@+id/cameragraph">

                                </RelativeLayout>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="180dip"
                                    android:layout_height="105dip" android:background="@drawable/graph_layout"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dip" android:id="@+id/image">

                                </RelativeLayout>
                                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="180dip"
                                    android:layout_height="105dip" android:background="@drawable/graph_layout"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dip" android:id="@+id/image">

                                </RelativeLayout>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="180dip"
                                    android:layout_height="105dip" android:background="@drawable/graph_layout"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dip" android:id="@+id/image">

                                </RelativeLayout>
                                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="180dip"
                                    android:layout_height="105dip" android:background="@drawable/graph_layout"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dip" android:id="@+id/image">

                                </RelativeLayout>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="180dip"
                                    android:layout_height="105dip" android:background="@drawable/graph_layout"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dip" android:id="@+id/image">

                                </RelativeLayout>
                                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="180dip"
                                    android:layout_height="105dip" android:background="@drawable/graph_layout"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dip" android:id="@+id/image">

                                </RelativeLayout>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="180dip"
                                    android:layout_height="105dip" android:background="@drawable/graph_layout"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dip" android:id="@+id/image">

                                </RelativeLayout>
                                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="180dip"
                                    android:layout_height="105dip" android:background="@drawable/graph_layout"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dip" android:id="@+id/image">

                                </RelativeLayout>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="180dip"
                                    android:layout_height="105dip" android:background="@drawable/graph_layout"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dip" android:id="@+id/image">

                                </RelativeLayout>
                                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="180dip"
                                    android:layout_height="105dip" android:background="@drawable/graph_layout"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dip" android:id="@+id/image">

                                </RelativeLayout>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableLayout>
                    </ScrollView>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
```

try this this. Just this is only layout.but not entire one

Comment: Let me know whether it is useful. you have to change the ids and set the description in strings.xml